# How to add multiple where condition in firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I would like to get a list where **deleteStataus**= no and **userID**= userID

Here is my existing code:

```
  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelMed> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelMed>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                                    child("medicines").orderByChild("userId").
                                    equalTo(mysharedPreferance.getUserID()),
                            ModelMed.class)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get a list where deleteStataus= no and userID= userID

What you are looking for is not currently supported. Firebase Realtime Database does not support queries on multiple properties, only supports queries on a single child property. So it can be one (`deleteStataus= no`) or the other (`userId= userId`), but not both.

There is however a workaround, in which you can create an extra field to keep the values of both fields. So your schema should look like this:

```
db
|
--- medicines
      |
      --- Calsin864247
           |
           --- deleteStataus: "no"
           |
           --- userId: "fahar@gmail"
           |
           --- deleteStataus_userId: "no_fahar@gmail"
           |
           --- //other fields.
```

As you can see, the `deleteStataus_userId` field combines the values that you want to filter on.

Different than the Firebase Realtime Database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). This means that a query such as the one below is allowed without the need of creating a combined property:

```
medicinesRef.whereEqualTo("deleteStataus", "no").whereEqualTo("userId", "fahar@gmail");
```

Comment: Hey Tanveer. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?